# I want to use up and down arrow keys and Calender dropdown in datetimepicker in Winforms C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying use up and down arrow key and calender dropdown using datetimepicker in C#.

When i am using `ShowUpDown=true` property of `DateTimePicker control` the arrow key get enabled but the calendar Drop-Down is disabled.

So please let me know how i can use up and down keys and calendar dropdown key in datetimepicker control

Comment: This bebaviour is [as documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.showupdown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): _"When the ShowUpDown property is set to true, a spin button control (also known as an up-down control), **rather than a drop-down calendar**, is used to adjust time values."_ You might have to add your own up-down control to have both.

Comment: How to add our own up-down spinner control ? Please suggest

Comment: Like any other control, you just drag it from the toolbox..?